# For C# and gRPC, which is the difference between protobuf-net and protobuf-net.Grpc?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Until now, I was using protobuf-netGrpc to use gPRC to transmit data between service and client. It works, I can create an interface as contract between the service and the client and I can use classes that I can decorate the DTOs with attributes like DataContract and DataMemeber, that belongs to System.Runtime.Serialization, to serialize the classes.

But now I have a problem, I would like to serialize a DateOnly property, but protobuf-grpc is not compatible with this type.

Searching information, protobuf-net is compatible with this type, [github project of protobuf-net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/issues/977).

In my project I don't have the protobuf-net package, I have only protobuf-net.Grpc and protobuf-net.Grpc.AspNetCore, so I am not using protobuf-net.

What is the difference between protobuf-net and protobuf-net.grpc? Could I use protobuf-net with protobuf-net.Grpc, to can use the code first solution and to have the benefits of protobuf-net? Because I have seen that that last update of protobuf-net.Grpc is in 2023-02-02 and it seems that protobuf-net is update more often, the last update is 2023-09-27.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Protobuf-net should be a dependency of protobuf-net.grpc. See the [Dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net.Grpc#dependencies-body-tab) tab. Note that Visual studio hides transitive dependencies in a subtree in the solution explorer. You could add a direct dependency if you want to use a later version of protobuf-net if you want, assuming there are no breaking changes.

Comment: that's true, under protobuf-net.Grpc, the protobuf-net is as depedency. However, the version that I have is the versión 2.4.8, but the last version is 3.2.30 according to the GitHub project. When I manage the nuget packages, I have all updated, so I am wondering if it would be possible to use the last version of protobuf-net with protobuf-net.Grpc.

Comment: If you just install the 3.2.30 package in nuget it should automatically add binding redirects etc to make it all work. But note that a new major version often indicate breaking changes. You may want to read the release notes, or just stick to the latest 2.* release.